# Кнопка со скруглёнными углами и тенью

Tags: android, xml, android-ui

Я рисовал новый стиль для кнопок в Skachat

Вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну вот я хотел реализовать это в android studio, на xml файле.
Но у меня не получается размыть задний белый тень.

Вот мой xml код:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid
                    android:color="#000000"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:right="3dp"
            android:top="3dp"
            android:bottom="3dp"
            android:left="3dp">

            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#9cffffff"/>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item
            android:right="8dp"
            android:top="8dp"
            android:bottom="8dp"
            android:left="8dp">

            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#000000" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Ну вот вопрос: Есть-ли способ этого реализовать, если есть то как?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Тут надо еще поле градиент.  Посмотри этот пример.

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:type="radial"
    android:gradientRadius="100dp"
    android:startColor="#00ffffff"
    android:endColor="#ad562121">
</gradient>

<stroke
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:width="5dp"/>

<size
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: _спасибо Игорь_

Comment: @JavohEgo Спасибо выражается кликом на галочку рядом с вопросом, отмечая его как принятый.

Comment: @VerNick просто я ждал еще других вариантов...

Comment: @JavohEgo Никто не будет отвечать, если видит что у ответа +7. Смысла не будет.

Comment: @VerNick хорошо, _спасибо за советь._

Answer (score 1):

Если кому интересно, я сделал похожий вариант

Вот xml код:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid
                    android:color="#000000"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                <stroke android:color="#1b1b1b"
                    android:width="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:right="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="2dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                <stroke android:color="#292929"
                    android:width="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:right="3dp"
            android:top="3dp"
            android:bottom="3dp"
            android:left="3dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                <stroke android:color="#505050"
                    android:width="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:right="4dp"
            android:top="4dp"
            android:bottom="4dp"
            android:left="4dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                <stroke android:color="#717171"
                    android:width="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                <stroke android:color="#999999"
                    android:width="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:right="6dp"
            android:top="6dp"
            android:bottom="6dp"
            android:left="6dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                <stroke android:color="#b9b9b9"
                    android:width="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item
            android:right="7dp"
            android:top="7dp"
            android:bottom="7dp"
            android:left="7dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                <stroke android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#ffffff"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Comment: то есть вы сделали семь слоев прямоугольников с постепенным "затуханием" цвета? не думаю, что это очень удачное решение, подумайте, сколько ресурсов потребуется, чтобы нарисовать ваш "бутерброд"

Comment: @pavlofff в коде нет семь слоев, там один чёрны слой и семь  "затухающий" линии. Это же лучше чем взять изображению в png формате.